# Iterating over np.arange gives incorrect results starting from i = 10

Tags: python, numpy

Iterating over np.arange gives incorrect results starting from i = 10

```py
import numpy as np
from math import pi, sqrt, exp, factorial

def pyas(x, sred):
    return sred**x*exp(-sred)/factorial(x)

for i, j in zip(np.arange(20), range(20)):
    print(i, j, pyas(i,10), pyas(j,10))
```

The question is, why do the values of the pyas() function start to differ?
The output:

```
0 0 4.5399929762484854e-05 4.5399929762484854e-05
1 1 0.00045399929762484856 0.00045399929762484856
2 2 0.0022699964881242427 0.0022699964881242427
3 3 0.007566654960414142 0.007566654960414142
4 4 0.018916637401035354 0.018916637401035354
5 5 0.03783327480207071 0.03783327480207071
6 6 0.06305545800345118 0.06305545800345118
7 7 0.09007922571921599 0.09007922571921599
8 8 0.11259903214901998 0.11259903214901998
9 9 0.1251100357211333 0.1251100357211333
10 10 0.01764133335640144 0.1251100357211333
11 11 0.001382752728810601 0.11373639611012118
12 12 -6.89413134691794e-05 0.09478033009176766
13 13 9.595669338819968e-06 0.07290794622443666
14 14 1.4396571374678832e-07 0.05207710444602619
15 15 -5.313583114618023e-08 0.03471806963068413
16 16 4.0683489446471356e-09 0.021698793519177577
17 17 2.0030859032126935e-10 0.012763996187751515
18 18 -1.0541774694098002e-11 0.007091108993195286
19 19 -7.394475413970681e-13 0.0037321626279975192
```

Comment: What does “gives incorrect results” mean exactly?

Comment: If you look at the output of the program, you will see that the output of the function, starting from i = 10, is different. The correct one is the one that is output when iterating by range()

Comment: Overflow in `10**np.int64(19)`, if you have `numpy` compiled with C long of type `int32`  (e.g. win10/win11 ) the overflow occurs earlier.

Comment: It would help to post the output and note the problem. At first glace, they all appeared the same for me except for the last one. `np.arange` is giving you `np.int64` which is different than `range` 's `int`.

Comment: As just mentioned by @tdelaney - I was about to recommend inspecting the data types as `arange` is likely using a 32 or 64-bit integer which will likely cause a variance to `range`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is that `np.arange` is iterating fixed size `np.int64` values while `range` is iterating python's unbounded `int`. We can see this by choosing the highest value in your range: 19.

```
>>> foo=10**np.int64(19)
>>> bar=10**19
>>> type(foo), type(bar)
(<class 'numpy.int64'>, <class 'int'>)
>>> foo, bar
(-8446744073709551616, 10000000000000000000)
```

The numpy version overflowed and wrapped to a negative number with a smaller absolute value. The python `int` is not limited to 64 bits and can expand indefinately.